# What is the best method for a large navigation menu - Array or Database?

Tags: php, arrays, database

I have to create a large navigation menu in PHP with ~20 list items with each having a sub menu of another ~20 and that also with it's own sub menu of another ~20.

That's around (20x20x20) 8,000 different items in the menu. I need to be able to manage this update/add/remove items.  I'm not sure if storing this in a database will be quick enough to load for the UX or setting it all in multidimensional arrays would prove faster and better to load as no DB requests needed therefore.

I'd like some advice on how to go about this task from more experienced programmers please?  I'm still new :)

Comment: Go with the elegant and clear solution that makes your code readable and maintainable. Performance is not an issue for this amount of records, whatever storage you go with.

Comment: Like @EmilePels said, with 8000 records you should be fine on most networks today... The best thing you could do for a better UI is use JavaScript lazy load, request a limited amount of data as needed. This should largely decrease any sort of latency you may be having.

Comment: Also, how would you store all of that data in an `array`? The database would be a more efficient method to store such large number of files.